# Adicionar linhas com o mesmo ID em colunas adicionais

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, pivot

Tenho o seguinte cenário de Tabela:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| ID    | DATA          |       PROFISSAO       |   SEQUENCIA |
+-------| --------------|-----------------------|-------------+
| 1     | 2018-01-01    |       Professor       |   1         |
| 1     | 2018-02-01    |       Ator            |   2         |
| 1     | 2018-03-01    |       Bombeiro        |   3         |
| 2     | 2018-01-01    |       Comerciante     |   1         |
| 2     | 2018-02-01    |       Motorista       |   2         |
| 2     | 2018-03-01    |       Analista        |   3         |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Porém quero obter o seguinte:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|ID |   DATA        |PROFISSAO      |DATA       |PROFISSAO      |DATA       |PROFISSAO  |
+---|---------------|---------------|-----------|---------------|-----------|-----------|
|1  |   2018-01-01  |Professor      |2018-02-01 |Ator           |2018-03-01 |Bombeiro   |
|2  |   2018-01-01  |Comerciante    |2018-02-01 |Motorista      |2018-03-01 |Analista   |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

A coluna SEQUENCIA foi enumerada (um *rank* no caso).

Acontece que os *PIVOTs* que vejo transformam os valores nas colunas e não adicionam à frente.

Não necessita ser um valor dinâmico pois sei quantas linhas no máximo eu terei, nesse caso serão 3.

Comment: Qual a `query` que você tem atualmente?

Comment: @Sorack no momento só montei a sequencia da primeira tabela. Realmente não estou dando conta de sair do lugar. Já utilizei PIVOT uma vez, porém com os dados virando coluna e não adicionando as colunas à frente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não precisa de um `pivot`. Você pode vincular a tabela com `JOIN`:

```
WITH resultado AS (
  -- Aqui vai sua query atual
)
SELECT r1.*,
       r2.*,
       r3.*
  FROM resultado r1
       LEFT JOIN resultado r2 ON r2.id = r1.id
                             AND r2.sequencia = 2
       LEFT JOIN resultado r3 ON r3.id = r1.id
                             AND r3.sequencia = 3
 WHERE r1.sequencia = 1
```

Veja funcionando no [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a53473/1).

Answer (score 2):

Utilize o pivot clássico:

```
-- código #1
SELECT ID,
       max(case when SEQUENCIA = 1 then DATA end) as [DATA 1],
       max(case when SEQUENCIA = 1 then PROFISSAO end) as [PROFISSAO 1],
       max(case when SEQUENCIA = 2 then DATA end) as [DATA 2],
       max(case when SEQUENCIA = 2 then PROFISSAO end) as [PROFISSAO 2],
       max(case when SEQUENCIA = 3 then DATA end) as [DATA 3],
       max(case when SEQUENCIA = 3 then PROFISSAO end) as [PROFISSAO 3]
  from Tabela
  group by ID;
```

Simples, prático e eficiente, pois efetua uma única leitura nos dados.

Comment: Fiddle usando a sua resposta: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/dab70/1

Comment: Realmente vendo o plano de execução a sua solução é bem mais performática