# SELECT apresentando o mesmo campo varias vezes, a partir de um cálculo

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Comecei a estudar banco de dados, estou usando o Postgres e me deparei com o a seguinte necessidade, tenho campo "pacotes" em uma na tabela "fluxo", onde preciso separar os pacotes por quantidade de "bytes" (outro registro da mesma tabela), 
consigo fazer essa apresentação em separado com os seguintes selects:

```
select idpontocli,sum(pacotes) as "<128"  from fluxo
where idpontocli= 51 and fluxo.time between '2020-05-23 11:15:00' and '2020-05-23 11:25:00' and (bytes/pacotes) <= 128 
group by dpontocli;

select idpontocli,sum(pacotes) as "<256"  from fluxo
where idpontocli= 51 and fluxo.time between '2020-05-23 11:15:00' and '2020-05-23 11:25:00' and (bytes/pacotes) > 128  and (bytes/pacotes) <= 256 
group by idpontocli;
```

Gostaria de saber se há possibilidade em um mesmo select fazer essa separação e apresentar um resultado do tipo:

```
idpontocli  |  <128 | <256 | <512 ...
```

Comment: Pesquise por pivot.

Comment: Agora que notei que apesar de ter colocado a tag `sql-server` no texto você informa utiliar `postgres`. Para o caso do PostgreSQL veja `crosstab` em `tablefunc` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Ajuda com um PIVOT ( Sql Server )](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/362219/ajuda-com-um-pivot-sql-server)

Comment: Relacionada: [Adicionar linhas com o mesmo ID em colunas adicionais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/301051/59479).

Answer (score 0):

Esse recurso chama-se "PIVOT" onde basicamente você faz um agrupamento de resultados de linhas em colunas específicas.

Para que possamos testar isso para você carregue os dados no [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/).

Esse exemplo parece bem simples de implemenar [aqui](https://www.vertabelo.com/blog/creating-pivot-tables-in-postgresql-using-the-crosstab-function/).

Na documentação oficial você pode encontrar nesse [link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/tablefunc.html).

Comment: Felipe, primeiramente obrigado pela resposta.
Tentei executar o select, tive até que ativar a function crosstab, mas acho que meu conhecimento é muito pouco e não obtive sucesso.
Quanto a colocar os dados naquele link, fiquei com alguma dúvida, mas tenho que informar que a tabela é gigante, acada cinco minutos são inseridos por volta de 15 a 20 mil registros, são informações de tráfego de rede.
Tentei te passar mais informações, mas o campo de comentário é pequeno. caso não dê para ajudar te agradeço.

Comment: @user190678 coloca somente um pedaço da tabela para podermos tentar ajudar. pega somente 1000 registros ou algo assim. esse link que eu passei ele deixa facilmente testarmos em um ambiente ai eu consigo ajustar a query para vc. O PIVOT é meio complicado porém depois que vc pega o jeito é de boas. QQ coisa coloca um script de create da tabela em algum lugar e mande o link por aqui ou no corpo da sua pergunta.